# Buggy scrolling div code

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a scrolling DIV element, It moves with the page as the you scroll.
It bugs sometimes when scrolling, Help?

JS Code:

```
window.onload = function() {

  function getScrollTop() {
    if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined' ) {
      return window.pageYOffset;
    }

    var d = document.documentElement;
    if (d.clientHeight) {
      return d.scrollTop;
    }

    return document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box'),
        scroll = getScrollTop();

    if (scroll <= 3) {
      box.style.top = "30px";
    }
    else {
      box.style.top = (scroll + 2) + "px";
    }
  };

};
```

Im new to javascript.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Provide a full example.  Please don't expect people to rebuild your entire HTML/CSS into a working example.  Also be more descriptive when you say "it bugs sometimes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS with position:fixed and it won't bug.